# imghdr.what() does not work on a BytesIO buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, png, imghdr

I am working on a feature that allows users to upload images to a Python-Flask web app.  The uploaded image is converted into a BytesIO buffer and is never saved to disk.  I want to use `imghdr.what()` to determine the image type (png, jpg, etc.) and see if it is a format that users are allowed to upload.  If the format is not allowed, the upload will be rejected.

Following the [imghdr.what() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/imghdr.html), I wrote the below code,

```py
    image_data.seek(0)
    image_type = imghdr.what(None, h=image_data.read())
    image_data.seek(0)
```

Unfortunately,when I call this with a png image, it returns `None` for `image_type`.  I tried the below variations with the same image.

```py
    image_data.seek(0)
    image_type = imghdr.what('', h=image_data.read())
    image_data.seek(0)
```

Again, the above returned `None` for `image_type`.

```py
    image_data.seek(0)
    image_type = imghdr.what(None, h=image_data)
    image_data.seek(0)
```

The above returns an error, `TypeError: '_io.BytesIO' object is not subscriptable`

```py
    image_data.seek(0)
    image_type = imghdr.what('', h=image_data.read)
    image_data.seek(0)
```

The above returns the same error, `TypeError: '_io.BytesIO' object is not subscriptable`

Here is the code from `conftest.py` where I create the mock png image,

```py
@pytest.fixture
def test_image_BytesIO():
    test_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    local_path = os.path.join(test_dir, 'images/204Cat.png')
    img_bytes = Pimage.open(local_path).tobytes()
    return BytesIO(img_bytes)
```

I've already looked at these resources:
[Examples of how to use imghdr.what()](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/3878/imghdr.what)
[Determine the type of an image in Python using imghdr](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/determine-type-image-python-using-imghdr/)

[Determing the type of an image using Python imghdr](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/determine-the-type-of-an-image-using-python-imghdr)

**TLDR**: How do I get `imghdr.what()` to work with an image that is in BytesIO format?

Comment: Why have you removed the `import` statements so nobody can run your code? Where does `Pimage` come from? What is the type of `image_data` and where does it come from and how is it created?